# Visual Basic: Filter Items from a listbox

Tags: visual-studio, listbox, items

I'm trying something seemingly simple but I've been cracking my head over this problem for days now.
All I want to do is when the button *'Filter'* is pressed, that all items that contain the string "Item" are removed from the listbox.

This is my current code:

```
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim amountItems As Integer = LSBItems.Items.Count - 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To amountItems
    LSBItems.SelectedIndex = index
    Dim l_text As String = LSBItems.SelectedItem.ToString
    If l_text.Contains("Item") Then
        LSBItems.Items.Remove(LSBItems.SelectedItem)
    End If
    index = index + 1
    Next
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has a similar problem, I was able to solve this issue using a reversed loop:

```
For i As Integer = LSBItems.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If LSBItems.Items(i).Contains("Item") Then
        LSBItems.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```